# The 'If' statement part is not being carried out

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, structure

I'm currently working on a project for school and it includes a login and register system.

This is a function that I have made. The "taken" variable will be passed back to the main program.

```
Dim taken As Boolean
Dim temp As String
For counter = 1 To totalrecords
    FileGet(1, player_info)
    temp = player_info.username
    If TextBox2.Text = temp Then 
      msgbox("this is a messagebox")
      taken = True
    End If
Next
```

This is the part of the code that checks if any usernames are in use. If so, taken = true and then a message is displayed.

Now, for some reason the if statement part is not being carried out. The message box does not show at all. I have tested this by using more than one same username and the second (same) username is still added to the file. I'm very confused.

Part I believe is not working  -

```
If TextBox2.Text = temp Then 
    taken = True
End If
```

Comment: if it's not executing at all, then something's weird. maybe your test is simply always failing. try adding an `else` clause and have `msgbox('this is the else clause')`. You'll probably get that message, in which case you have to figure out why your equality test fails.

Comment: What is the value of `totalRecords`?. If it is zero then the for loop never executes. Put a breakpoint on the initial line of the loop and check the value of totalRecords

Comment: Put a msgbox before your `FileGet` line as well. This will tell you if you have any `totalrecords`. You may not even fall into the loop.

Comment: I have added a condition where if the totalRecords > 0 then it will carry out this code.

It still creates the account, I don't know why. Any other ideas guys?

Comment: Use the debugger.  Put a breakpoint on the `If TextBox2...` line, and inspect the values of your variables.  You should immediately see why it is not passing the If test.

Answer (score 0):

You should use String.Equals(String1, String) to compare TextBox text and the temp variable.
In your case it should be written as this.

```
If String.Equals(TextBox2.Text, temp) Then
   taken = true
End if
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but it still goes on to make the account.
I don't know what's wrong, and I am very confused.
Any other ideas?

Comment: Why use String.Equals?  The comparison operator (=) is overloaded to compare strings properly and it is more readable.